# minimise logic function using K-map

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I was asked to minimise the following logic function using K-map:

(,,) = ''' + ' + ' +

Then, I tried to construct the following k-map (not sure if this is correct), and don't know what's the next step. Should I using the Algebraic simplification first?

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& y'z'& y'z & yz & yz' \\ \hline
x' &1 & &1&1\\ \hline
x&  &1 &1&1\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, your KM is correct. Can you see in it that the function can be written as $y+xz+x'z'?$

Comment: oh.. I can that now after pairing, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, @lelebird